# Sort an array in a peculiar order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I've been trying to figure out how to solve this problem but I can't seem to find the proper sorting order.

Instructions:

Write a program that orders a list of numbers in the following way:

3,-2,1,0,-1,0,-2,1 =>  -2,-1,-2,0,0,3,1,1

```
'use strict';
let myNumbers = '3,-2,1,0,-1,0,-2,1';
// I receive the input as a string and split and map it into an array
let myNumbers = gets().split(',').map(Number);
```

I've tried applying the sort() method in ascending order to all integers below zero and doing the opposite for those above but that's not quite the order in the expected output.

I've also attempted to splice the first array after applying sort() to 0 and then re-arrange the spliced part and concatenate it. However, that won't work with all test inputs.

Another example:
3,-12,0,0,13,5,1,0,-2 => -12,-2,0,0,0,3,13,5,1

What is the logic in this order? Thanks.

Comment: So this is more of a logical question? I mean there is some hidden logic in how the numbers should be sorted and we need to figure it out?

Comment: Yep. I has to be accomplished with array methods.

Answer (score 4):

Because this sounds like the solution to a homework problem or something of the like, I'll let you write the code:) But the way I would do it is in one iteration through the array, create three separate arrays:

1. Negative numbers
2. 0s
3. Positive numbers

Squish the arrays together without sorting and you have your O(N) solution.

Comment: The order is the order they appear. (3,-2,1,0,-1,0,-2,1 => -2,-1,-2,0,0,3,1,1) -2 is the first negative number in the list, so it comes first.
-1 is the next negative number, so it is next. continue through all negatives, then 0s are next. 3 is the first positive number, so it is next

Comment: In the second example, the first negative number is -12. The second is -2. That is how they appear in the expected output.

Comment: No problem! I do things like that all the time. Sometimes it's just hard to see the obvious answer.

Comment: @sketrik and who are the people who creates such tasks? Are these tasks to test IQ or something?

Answer (score 1):

So based on sketrik answer which covers the logic, this is the code:

```js
const myNumbers = '3,-2,1,0,-1,0,-2,1';
const arr = myNumbers.split(',').map(Number)

const res = arr.filter(i => i < 0)
.concat(arr.filter(i => i === 0))
.concat(arr.filter(i => i > 0))

console.log(res)
```

This works thanks to two very basic JS methods of Array.prototype:

[concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). I could not explain them better than the documentation, check it out!

But basically, what I am doing is:

1. find the chunk with negatives with `arr.filter(i => i < 0)`
2. find the chunk with zeros with `arr.filter(i => i === 0)`
3. find the chunk with positives with `arr.filter(i => i > 0)`
4. `concat` them all into one array.

Comment: This looks more advanced, I'll check it out. Thanks.

Comment: If you could go into a bit of detail about your solution, it would be great.

Comment: @Pavel I've added the details, Pavel

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, fixed by casting strings to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I am Neo.

```js
'use strict';
let myInput = '3,-2,1,0,-1,0,-2,1';
let myNumbers = myInput.split(',').map(Number);
let negatives = [];
let zeroes = [];
let positives = [];
for (const element of myNumbers) {
    if (element < 0) {
        negatives.push(element);
    } else if (element === 0) {
        zeroes.push(element);
    } else if (element > 0) {
        positives.push(element);
    }
}
let sortedArr = negatives.concat(zeroes, positives);
console.log(sortedArr.join(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

## Logic or Typo?

> ***"...ascending order to all integers below zero and doing the opposite for those above..."***

Following what was posted in question the examples should be:

**`-2, -2, -1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1`**  and  **`-12, -2, 0, 0, 0, 13, 5, 3, 1`**

Zero and less ascending: `-3, -2, -1, 0`. Greater than zero descending: `3, 2, 1`

To get those results see **Demo 1**.

---

Strictly going by the examples is simpler:

**`-2, -1, -2, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1`** and **`-12, -2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 13, 5, 1`**

Group negative numbers, then zeros, and then positive numbers: **`[-][0][+]`**. **No order within the three arrays is required. Order is only required for the three groups.**

To get those results see **Demo 2**.

---

### Explanation

**Demo 1**

1. First, sort array in ascending order:

   > **const ordered = array[.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)((current, next) => current - next);**
2. Next, find the index of the first number that's greater than 0, then extract all numbers beginning at that index and ending at the last number. Store the extracted array in a variable:

   > **const positive = ordered[.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)(ordered[.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)(number => number > 0));**
3. Finally, sort extracted array in descending order and then concatenate the extracted array to the end of the original array:

   > **return ordered[.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)(positive.sort((current, next) => next - current));**

**Demo 2**

1. Create three new arrays returned by the `filter()` method: negative (`n < 0`), zero (`n === 0)`, and positive (`n > 0`).
2. Then concatenate them into one array:

   > **const negative = array.filter(number => number < 0);**
   >
   > **const zero = array.filter(number => number === 0);**
   >
   > **const positive = array.filter(number => number > 0);**
   >
   > **return negative.concat(zero, positive);**

---

### Demo 1

```js
const unorderedA = [3, -2, 1, 0, -1, 0, -2, 1];
const unorderedB = [3, -12, 0, 0, 13, 5, 1, 0, -2];

const illogical = array => {
  const ordered = array.sort((current, next) => current - next);
  const positive = ordered.splice(ordered.findIndex(number => number > 0));
  return ordered.concat(positive.sort((current, next) => next - current));
};

// For demonstration purposes

const log = data => {
  const string = Array.isArray(data) ? `[${data.join(', ')}]` : data;
  return console.log(string);
};

log(illogical(unorderedA));
log(illogical(unorderedB));
```

### Demo 2

```js
const unorderedA = [3, -2, 1, 0, -1, 0, -2, 1];
const unorderedB = [3, -12, 0, 0, 13, 5, 1, 0, -2];

const illogical = array => {
  const negative = array.filter(number => number < 0);
  const zero = array.filter(number => number === 0);
  const positive = array.filter(number => number > 0);
  return negative.concat(zero, positive);
};

// For demonstration purposes

const log = data => {
  const string = Array.isArray(data) ? `[${data.join(', ')}]` : data;
  return console.log(string);
};

log(illogical(unorderedA));
log(illogical(unorderedB));
```

Comment: I did now, thanks @NurbolAlpysbayev updated to coincide with question.